# generate dates and add new property to array of object

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have no control over a list of data, but I need to map it to a date range data.

The list of data look like this, which only have from and to.

```
[
    {
        "date_from": "2017-05-06 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-08 23:59:59",
        "state": {
            "name": "San francisco"
        }
    }
    {
        "date_from": "2017-05-03 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-07 23:59:59",
        "state": {
            "name": "Las Vegas"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm able to generate a date range base on month

```
function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push({
      date: moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dateArray;
}

generateDates('2017-05-01', '2017-05-31');
```

How can I put the state object into the date range array like

```
[
{date: '2017-05-06', state:{name:'San francisco'}},
{date: '2017-05-07', state:{name:'San francisco'}},
{date: '2017-05-08', state:{name:'San francisco'}},
..
..
]
```

Comment: you will have to add state in date before pushing it to dateArray. I am afraid that has to be done by iterating through list for each generated date. You can optimize it further by sorting the list and also validations should be there for multiple matches.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831941/split-from-date-and-to-date-to-a-list-of-date-range-array/43832057?noredirect=1# ...

Comment: Your dates do not have time zones, which one should be used?

Answer (score 0):

**You can run nested loops and flat function to achieve the resultant output**

```js
const inputList = [
    {
        "date_from": "2017-05-06 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-08 23:59:59",
        "state": {
            "name": "San francisco"
        }
    },
    {
        "date_from": "2017-05-03 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-07 23:59:59",
        "state": {
            "name": "Las Vegas"
        }
    }
];

function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var endDate = moment(stopDate);
  while (currentDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
    dateArray.push({
      date: moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dateArray;
}

const generateRange = (inputList) => {

    return inputList.map(({date_from, date_to, state}) => {
        return generateDates(date_from, date_to).map((entry) => ({
            ...entry,
            state,
        }))
    }).flat();
}

const output = generateRange(inputList);

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var sparse=input.reduce((sparse,event)=>generateDates(event.date_from,event.date_to).forEach(date=>(sparse[date]=sparse[date]||[]).push(event))||sparse,{});

var result=[];
for(date in sparse){
 result.push({date:date,states:sparse[date].map(el=>el.state)});
}
```

http://jsbin.com/larumiyeli/edit?console

Or if you dont want to group:

```
  var result=input.reduce((sparse,event)=>sparse.concat(generateDates(event.date_from,event.date_to).map(el=>(el.state=event.state,el)),[]);
```

http://jsbin.com/mixorecoyo/edit?console

For explanation see other answer... Looks like theres a class out here isnt it? ;)

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, mark it as a duplicate. There's not much point in posting code then linking to the answer that has the explanation. Also, far better to post your code here as a runnable snippet than to link to an external site.

Comment: @RobG the questions arent equal in any way. I dont wanted to destroy the progress he made... And concerning snippets: *snippets can not be used on mobile*...