# split from_date and to_date to a list of date range array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs

How can I transform from this array

```
[
    {
        "date_from": "2017-05-06 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-08 23:59:59",
        "event": "code jam"
    },
    {
        "date_from": "2017-05-03 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-07 23:59:59",
        "event": "boxing day"
    }
]
```

to this?

```
[
..
..
{date: '2017-05-06', state:{name:'San francisco'}},
{date: '2017-05-07', state:{name:'San francisco'}},
{date: '2017-05-08', state:{name:'San francisco'}},
..
..
]
```

I have no clue where to start. I'm given an API where I can't change it structure, I need the data to be in a list of date range so I can map with a calendar plugin. Need help.

Comment: do you want it to show on every date in between or just on the start/end date?

Comment: @Jonasw every date, that's the major challenge.

Comment: thats good... my guessing was right...

Comment: @Jonasw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830877/generate-dates-and-add-new-property-to-array-of-object?noredirect=1#comment74702058_43830877

Answer (score 1):

At first, iterate over the events, then loop over the events dates and store the events at these dates:

```
var output=input.reduce(function(obj,event){
   for(var day=Math.floor(+new Date(event.date_from)/(1000*60*60*24)+1),max=Math.floor(+new Date(event.date_to)/(1000*60*60*24));day<=max;day++){
       (obj[day]=obj[day]||[]).push(event);
   }
 return obj;
},{});
```

Then create an array out of that object ( and shorten the date) :

```
Date.prototype.format=function(str){
var map={
  dd:this.getDate(),
  mm:this.getMonth()+1,
  yyyy:this.getFullYear()
}
return str.split("-").map(el=>map[el]||"00").join("-");
}


var arr=[];
for(key in output){
  arr.push({date:new Date(key*1000*60*60*24).format("dd-mm-yyyy"),events:output[key]});
}
console.log(arr);
```

http://jsbin.com/jonaqefaxu/edit?console

Comment: this work but this look too messy to maintain, my senior won't let me commit this code for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
    {
        "date_from": "2017-05-06 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-08 23:59:59",
        "event": "code jam"
    },
    {
        "date_from": "2017-05-03 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-07 23:59:59",
        "event": "boxing day"
    }
];

var transformedData = data
  .map(datum => [{date: datum.date_from.substr(0, 10)}, {date: datum.date_to.substr(0, 10)}])
  .reduce((allItems, items) => allItems.concat(items), [])
  .map(item => ({date: item.date, state: {name:'San francisco'}}));

console.log(transformedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new array using data from the previous array.

```js
 var data = [{
        "date_from": "2017-05-06 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-08 23:59:59",
        "event": "code jam"
      },
      {
        "date_from": "2017-05-03 00:00:00",
        "date_to": "2017-05-07 23:59:59",
        "event": "boxing day"
      }
    ];

    var newData =[]
    data.forEach(function(item){
      newData.push({
      date:item['date_from'].slice(0, -9), // removing characters from last
      state:{
      name:'Some State'}
      })             

    });
    console.log(newData)
```