# Generate date range given date from and to

Tags: javascript, datetime, ecmascript-6, momentjs, lodash

I have an array of object:

```
[{from:'2017-05-02',to:'2017-05-12',event:'google map launch day'},
{from:'2017-05-03',to:'2017-05-14',event:'marie"s farewell'},
{from:'2017-05-20',to:'2017-05-20',event:'iphone showcase'}]
```

I want to map the event property to array of object below

```
[{
date: "2017-05-01"
},
{
date: "2017-05-02",
event: ['google map launch day']
},
{
date: "2017-05-03",
event: ['google map launch day', 'marie"s farewell']
},
{
date: "2017-05-04",
event: ['google map launch day', 'marie"s farewell']
}
..
]
```

https://pastebin.com/raw/Uv3U8zCy

I have no control over the first array of object, it came from an external API, I want to build a custom calendar, I'm struggling to map to a new format of array of object.

```
function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push({ date: moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') });
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dateArray;
}

generateDates('2017-05-01', '2017-05-31');
```

I'm able to generate days of a month using momentjs but I'm still stuck.

Comment: why are you asking the same question two times? http://stackoverflow.com/a/43833684/5260024

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table as reference to the generated dates and iterate later in the same style the events.

```js
function getRanges(data, startDate, stopDate) {
    function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
        var currentDate = moment(startDate),
            stopDate = moment(stopDate),
            date;
      
        while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
            date = moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            hash[date] = { date: date };
            dateArray.push(hash[date]);
            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
        }
    }

    var dateArray = [],
        hash = {};

    generateDates(startDate, stopDate);

    data.forEach(function (a) {
        var currentDate = moment(a.from),
            stopDate = moment(a.to),
            date;

        while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
            date = moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            hash[date].event = hash[date].event || [];
            hash[date].event.push(a.event);
            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
        }
    });
    return dateArray;
}

var data = [{ from: '2017-05-02', to: '2017-05-12', event: 'google map launch day' }, { from: '2017-05-03', to: '2017-05-14', event: 'marie"s farewell' }, { from: '2017-05-20', to: '2017-05-20', event: 'iphone showcase' }];


console.log(getRanges(data, '2017-05-01', '2017-05-31'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) of moment.js and get Events from iterating date as below.

```
var eventData = [{from:'2017-05-02',to:'2017-05-12',event:'google map launch day'},
{from:'2017-05-03',to:'2017-05-14',event:'marie"s farewell'},
{from:'2017-05-20',to:'2017-05-20',event:'iphone showcase'}]

// Get events for passed date
function getEvents(curDate){
   return eventData.reduce(function(res,obj){
     if(moment(curDate).isBetween(obj.from, obj.to, null, '[]'))
         res.push(obj.event);
      return res;
   },[])

}

function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push({ 
       date: moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
       event:getEvents(currentDate) // Get events array here
     });
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dateArray;
}
```